# Is there a way to remove the Ref and Value markings from the preview and final print?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, kicad

I just started using KiCad.

The "Ref" and "Value" markings are getting quite frustrating.

I can remove them from the design preview by disabling some layers, but when I open it in the 3D viewer they are still visible.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3D Viewer, go to *Display Options* menu either by clicking the third button on the top toolbar or using the *Preferences* menu. There you can uncheck the *Show silkscreen layers* checkbox.

Normally, only references are shown in 3D viewer, not the values because they are part of the Fab layers. The solution I mentioned hides the all silkscreen layers. I don't know any option to hide references only.

Plotting to Gerber, you can selectively disable the footprint values and reference designators using these checkboxes:

[image: KiCad Gerber Plot Dialog]

Comment: Will they still be printed if I send it to a PCB manufacturer? (Note I haven't actually sent one before, don't know if they would normally print it)

Comment: they shouldn't but examine the GERBERS post generation (which you should always do).

Comment: @JonRB Alright ,thank you.